# create app which required visitors to click like or subscribe to email newsletter

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I want to create an app which will be included in my facebook fan page. 
That app will have two things:
1. I would like to protect my wall, so the wall posts will be only visible to people which clicked like on that page, 
2. I would like to have a textbox and button and the users will be able to signup for our newsletter. 
Any idea how I can do one or both of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide your wall from people that are not fans.  But if you create a custom fan page tab, you can set that as the default landing tab for your page.  The [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/) shows you want you need to do to build the sign up page you are describing.  It will obviously require some custom coding to store those emails somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For an email subscription mechanism, there are ready made apps that provide this, like [mailchimp](https://apps.facebook.com/mailchimp/).